# MongoDB loads but breaks, returning status=14

Tags: mongodb

So im trying to setup Mongodb on Ubuntu 16.04 but im running into trouble.

when running :

```
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

I get the following:

```
 mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2016-09-10 14:02:22 CEST; 14s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 8724 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
 Main PID: 8724 (code=exited, status=14)
```

According to the mongo-docs, status=14 is:

```
"Returned by MongoDB applications which encounter an unrecoverable error, an uncaught exception or uncaught signal. The system exits without performing a clean shut down."
```

I doesnt really point me in any particular direction.

My `/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service` looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any thought on what may be the cause of this?

Thank you

Comment: What does the MongoDB log say (usually in `/var/log`)?

Comment: Hey Adam, sorry for not getting back here. I did solve the problem by reinstalling mongo.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 252):

After googling around for a while. I found that that is because the permission settings on
`/var/lib/mongodb` and `/tmp/mongodb-27017.lock` are wrong. You will have to change the owner to monogdb user

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

then

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Comment: +1 for finding the undocumented `chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`...

Comment: +1 for `chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb`

Comment: I have lost yesterday just because of it. You should have good googling skills :)

Comment: Hi

I did change the permissions as above but still I'm unable to create a replica set which exits with error 14.Any ideas?

Here is the link that I'm using https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-change-streams-with-python

Comment: This resolved my issue.. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This answer literally saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: I have to do this EVERYTIME I want to start mongo...sucks, why???

Comment: This worked perfectly!

Comment: It saved my day

Comment: I had to use your solution. Thanks. I report I created the problem myself by trying to run the service from the command line as root as: `/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`. Like that file permission you mention were mangled and set to root.

Comment: chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb did it for me , you are a hero

Comment: It works for me after googling for 2 days.

Comment: it's solved my problem on production, thank you

Comment: Resolved my issue thank you so much.

Comment: You are the messiah!!

Comment: You saved me !!!

Comment: Just applied that for me :
```shell
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo systemctl restart mongod
sudo systemctl status mongod
```
Status was anew good after.

Answer (score 14):

By using this my error was gone:

1. Go to the `TMP` directory: `cd /tmp`
2. Check if you have the mongodb sock file: `ls *.sock`
3. Change the user:group permission: `chown mongodb:mongodb <YOUR_SOCK>`
4. Start MongoDB: `sudo service mongod start`
5. Check the MongoDB status: `sudo service mongod status`

Comment: in tmp i have no `.sock` files. What possibly can go wrong?

Comment: when i try to do it, it says operation not permitted, any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

deleting the mongod sock file solved the issue for me `sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`
then start again `sudo systemctl start mongod`

Answer (score 5):

1. Check for both mentioned directories
   If they don't exist, use the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mongodb
sudo mkdir /var/log/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
```

2. Clear the socket with the following command:

```
chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

3. Restart and check the status of the service:

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Comment: Just a small correction in response to your valuable answer in step 2 we need to add *sudo*  before chown.......

Answer (score 3):

i tried this and it worked :

```
sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf
```

comment the "bind ip" line.

```
sudo mongod --auth --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db
```

then i ran

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I also got status 14 at some point, but it was not because of my .lock files.

Looks like everything in your dbPath (in my case /data/mongodb) should belong to mongodb. In my case, two files and files in the journal folder were owned by root, possibly because I have run the mongod command with sudo instead of the mongodb user (as configured in mongod.service).

```
sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /data/mongodb/ -R
```

---

In order to find my problem, it helped to set the verbosity to 5 in /etc/mongod.conf:

```
systemLog:
  verbosity: 5
```

and run `tail /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log -n 100` after `sudo systemctl start mongod`

For this to work, mongod.conf needs to be loaded by mongod. mongod.service does that with the --config parameter.

Make sure to remove the high verbosity when your mongodb works again, because that logfile can grow very large.

Answer (score 1):

for beginners only if you are trying the following and getting errors :

```
  sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
  sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock 
  sudo service mongod restart
```

then try checking the status

```
  sudo systemctl status mongod
```

it will show active ..

Answer (score 0):

**Only in case of a fresh install:**
If `/var/lib/mongodb` is corrupt, `rm`ing it and reinstalling mongodb will work.

**For a database with pre-existing data try:**

```
mongod --repair --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred for me just because the disk space was full.
And solved after deleting some unused files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because of an incomplete repair operation, in which case I had to run `mongod --repair --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb`.