# Failed to install Mongodb-org in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, 22.04, mongodb

tried installing mongodb-org several times in my ubuntu 22.04 and followed many youtube videos as well as document tutorials but failed to install it.

`{"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:57:58.874+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:57:58.879+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}} {"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:57:58.879+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:57:58.879+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."} {"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:57:58.882+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:57:58.882+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}} {"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:57:58.882+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}} {"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:57:58.882+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"} {"t":{"$date":"2022-10-14T23:57:58.883+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":6365,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"naeemgg"}}`

running `mongod` showing the above and checking status shows

`mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-10-14 23:13:54 IST; 53min ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Process: 2037 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
Main PID: 2037 (code=exited, status=14)
CPU: 964ms

Oct 14 23:13:53 johns systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Oct 14 23:13:54 johns systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1>
Oct 14 23:13:54 johns systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.`

Running `mongo` shows :

`MongoDB shell version v5.0.13 connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17 @(connect):2:6 exception: connect failed exiting with code 1`

Comment: I just setup MongoDB 6.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 and I got it to work.  It is a bit unconventional right now since MongoDB repos are not ready for 22.04 yet or they are still under construction.  See https://askubuntu.com/a/842599/231142 and it is the bottom section of my answer titled Ubuntu22.04 and MongoDB 6.0.

Comment: I followed the same steps as you described in your answer @Terrance but end up with     mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-10-16 21:18:07 IST; 15s >
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 11577 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=ex>
   Main PID: 11577 (code=exited, status=14)
        CPU: 881ms

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/823288/mongodb-loads-but-breaks-returning-status-14

Answer (score 0):

use systemctl instead of service. Also after installing delete the sock file

> sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mongodb-27017.sock

Then restart mongodb with systemctl as it uses SystemD in latest Ubuntu releases or even in Ubuntu older version like 20.04 LTS

> sudo systemctl start mongod

Running with service causes errors